# GWT 2.9.0 Cannot compile application

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to update GWT from 2.8.2 to 2.9.0, but my application is failed to compile.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.9.0:compile (default) @ some-gwt-project ---
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'com.example.AppEntryPointDev'
[INFO]    Module location: file:/C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/project/target/project/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/AppEntryPointDev.gwt.xml
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
... skiped other module loading messages
[INFO] Public resources found in...
[INFO] Translatable source found in...
[INFO] Persistent unit cache dir set to: C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\project\target\gwt-unitCache
[INFO] Opening cache file: C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\project\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-8c530...
[INFO] Looking for previously cached Compilation Units in C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\project\target\gwt-unitCache
[INFO] Compiling module com.example.AppEntryPointDev
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker$CompileDependencyVisitor.<init>(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:59)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:227)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:166)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:41)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:36)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:100)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:349)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:532)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:464)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:210)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:190)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:131)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:192)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:143)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:132)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:110)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:113)
```

Application compiles fine with v2.8.2. I'm also using GXT 4.0.0, restyGWT 2.2.4 and mvp4g 1.5.0

Comment: Clear the gwt-unitcache and try again.

Comment: @ElHoss there is no cache prior to compilation. I'm doing clean install.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message is dreadful, but it means you have an old version of `asm.jar` ([org.ow2.asm/asm](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm)) on your classpath, probably pulled in via some other dependency in your project.

The GWT2.9 compiler requires `asm-7.1.jar` or later.

Comment: You are my lifesaver :D Thank you so much!. I've checked and found that I was using asm-5.0.3. After updating all working fine